# Android Application Download data

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-linearlayout

I'm developing a large application this is almost 50mb.
I was wondering how i can get the application itself to be like 5mb
But when the user opens the application it give a dialog to download the application data.

Comment: you didn't really specify why or what you're doing.  I assume that your app is so large because you've got a lot of static data, and the user doesn't need all of it, is this the case?  If so, you should note it.  Why do you want the app size to be smaller if the user needs all the data?  Presumably you can ask the user to download the material after the fact, but only if it's really optional.

Comment: what makes your app be so big? try compressing your data in your resources.

Comment: Sorry im a noob, you didnt have  to vote down.The user needs the data but i want the user to be able to download the data in the applicatio n from a  internet source.

Comment: My app has more than 5000 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/hsDu%20%28Android%20Developers%20Blog%29) blog post as it sounds like exactly what you want